# Allow conditional usage of semicolon in regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following pattern:

```
UnallowedCharacters = @"<>\{\}" + "\"";
@"^(?<contactType>\d+):(?<contactIdentifier>[^;" + UnallowedCharacters + @"]+)(;(?<parameterName>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)=(?<parameterValue>[^;=" + UnallowedCharacters + "]+))*$"
```

I need to allow the usage of semicolon in the `contactIdentifier` part, but still to not exclude the semicolon from not allowed chars, because the later split will not work anymore.

Two examples of input and expected output are the following:

- input: `"8:test;aliases=1:test@outlook.com,4:test"` => after parsing, expected output should be `"8:test"` for `contactIdentifier` part
- input: `"8.test;.person@domain.com;aliases=1:test@outlook.com,4:test"` => after parsing, expected output should be `"8:test;.person@domain.com"` for `contactIdentifier` part

The semicolons are used for splitting the unparsed string into multiple parts during parsing, but I want to allow using it in `contactIdentifer` character group without affecting the existing matching & parsing logic.

Any ideas?

Comment: `UnallowedCharacters` does not currently contain a semicolon, so, problem solved? If not, please post sample input (valid and invalid)

Comment: See later edit. :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the question, you can do this:

```
UnallowedCharacters = @"<>{}"""; (no need to escape inside a character group)

(?<contactIdentifier>(?:[;]|[^" + UnallowedCharacters + @"])+
```

**Explanation**:

I changed the `<contactIdentifier>` group to :

`?<contactIdentifier>` the name

`(?:` start of (non capturing) group

`[;]|` ';' OR:

`[^" + UnallowedCharacters + @"]` one character not in class

`)+` The whole group repeated one or more times.